# Version bumping same branch works only for first bump commit

Tags: azure-devops, cakebuild, gitversion

I found strange "issue", or rather behavior with GitVersion. Consider the following:

We work in dev branch, version is 0.1.0. I commit something to it with "+semver: minor" message. Nice, version is incremented, 0.2.0, we can go on, create a package, etc. We continue our work, I made new changes, committing with "+semver: minor" again. But version is still 0.2.0. What is the problem? I guess I don't understand how gitversion works or supposed to work.

Even if I try to create new branch from dev, then make bump commit in it, it still does not increment version again.

My goal is to have a simple workflow: Master branch for publishing new packages, we can branch from it, add some changes, bump version depending on type of task with commit message, then merge it back to master. Sounds simple, but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that GitVersion will only apply the `+semver: minor` once between tags.  For example, let's say you have tagged your repository at `0.1.0`, then the following commit messages:

```
+semver: minor Fixing something
+semver: minor Fixing something else
```

Will only result in a single bumping of the minor version.

However, if you did something like:

```
+semver: minor Fixing something
tag the repository at 0.2.0
+semver: minor Fixing something else
```

Then you will get a bump to 0.3.0.

Comment: Wow. I thought the whole reason of commit message bump was possibility to do it without providing new tag.

Comment: I would have to check the source code, but I am fairly sure that a tag is always needs to establish the current base version of the repository, and from there, things like commits messages are used to establish the current version.  If you are using the pre-release version of GitVersion you can use the /diag switch to establish how the version number is being established.

Comment: and it makes perfectly sense if you see a commit as a patch